# Perform optimization with F# and Accord.net

Tags: linq, f#, mathematical-optimization, accord.net

I'm using F# with Accord.NET, and I'm trying to perform an optimization using the Nelder-Mead algorithm.
After a week of attempts, trying to follow the examples from website, I still can't perform the operation.
I didn't find the way to write the expression for optimize the function.
I wrote a custom function which accept 9 parameters:

```
let FunSqEuclid (F:float) (X:float[]) (T:float) (iv:float[]) (atmVol:float) (alpha:float) (beta:float) (volVol:float) (rho:float) =
    let dum01 = VecAlphaSABR (F:float) (X:float[]) (T:float) (atmVol:float) (alpha:float) (beta:float) (volVol:float) (rho:float)

    let dum02 = Array.map2 (+) dum01 iv
    let dum03 = dum02.SquareEuclidean()

    dum03
```

What I need is to optimize this function varying only the "volVol" and "rho" parameters, but keeping constant all the others.

Following examples (in C#), I tried with:

```
let ObFunc = NonlinearObjectiveFunction(function: () => (FunSqEuclid (F:float) (X:float[]) (T:float) (iv:float[]) (atmVol:float) (alpha:float) (beta:float) (volVol:float) (rho:float)))
```

using costraints to keep parameters constant, but I have error on keyword "function", both for `NonlinearObjectiveFunction` and `NonlinearCostraint`.

I read on documentation that objective function can be written as a Linq Expression, but I never used it.

There is an alternative way to insert objective function and costraints? Or, please, can you suggest where are similar examples in Linq Expression for F#?

**EDIT**

I found more informations from the examples of "Extreme Optimization" library. I have seen it has a similar approach to "Accord.net" about the optimization, and there are examples in F#, so, with appropriate adaptations, I understand how it works when parameters are simple values.

The point is that I'm trying to translate some R code to F#.
The R code performing the optimization is the following:

```
objective <- function(x){sum( (iv - SABR.BSIV(t, f, K, exp(x[1]), .t1(x[2]), .t2(x[3]), exp(x[4])))^2) }
x <- nlm(objective, c(0.2, 1.0, 0.0, 0.1))
```

where K and iv are arrays. So, I still didn't find a way to pass array arguments for the objective function in Accord.net.

Please, can you suggest me some way?

Thanks.

Comment: "but I have error on keyword..." It would be helpful if you told us what exact error you have.  (But check your syntax: there shouldn't be a colon there (`:`), and there are other syntax problems, like `=>` instead of `->`, and you probably want the `fun` keyword instead of `function`.)

Comment: The error I have is `This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not requested`. The point is that following the examples in C#, it seems to me that `function:` is part of the syntax to define the objective function with Accord.

Comment: But F# has different syntax from C#! Both languages support lambda expressions and named arguments, but the syntax for each is different.  What is the signature of NonlinearObjectiveFunction?

Comment: I understand, but my C# knowledge is very poor. Please, can you suggest  (if any) a quick reference or examples to translate this kind of code from C# to F#? Thanks.

Comment: The signature of NonlinearObjectiveFunction is, from documentation: `NonlinearObjectiveFunction(Expression<Func<Double>>, Expression<Func<Double[]>>)` and from Visual Studio Intellisense: `NonlinearObjectiveFunction(function: Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<float>>, ?gradient: Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<float[]>>): unit `

Comment: So there's your problem: you're passing a function when it needs an expression tree. The C# compiler will compile a lambda expression into either, depending on the context, but the F# compiler doesn't do that.

Comment: @phoog, thank you to try to help me. I never used Linq before, and I asked if someone knows an alternative way to pass the function, or if, somewhere, there are some examples for F#.